# Retrieve latest invoice record with all related adjustment details

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to retrieve the latest invoice record (table may contains duplicate invoices) with all relevant adjustment details.
Unfortunately, the below SQL only able to retrieve a single line of record. (e.g. if the particular latest invoice has multiple charge code, it will only retrieve 1 of it)

SELECT a.Invoice, a.Shipment_Nbr, a.Invoice_date, b.Adjust_rsn, b.Adjust_date, c.Charge_code, c.Charge_Amt
FROM Invoicing a
Inner Join Adjust b
on a.Shipment_Nbr=b.Shipment_Nbr
Inner Join Charge c
on b.uniq_id=c.uniq_id
WHERE b.Adjust_date between '05-01-2022' and '05-31-2022'
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY
a.Shipment_Nbr
ORDER BY a.Invoice_date DESC) = 1

Refer to the image on the tables, current result and the expected result.
[Tables, Current Result & Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Q7I.png)

Comment: Simply switch to `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks. This works.
How do I sum up the charge_amt if there are multiple same charge_code for the same shipment_nbr?

Comment: Wrap the result in a Derived Table and do a Group Sum partition by Shipment_Nbr

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do it

```
select
a.Invoice, b.Shipment_Nbr, a.Invoice_date, b.Adjust_rsn, b.Adjust_date, c.Charge_code, c.Charge_Amt 
FROM
(
select * from Invoicing a
qualify (row_number() over (partition by Shipment_Nbr order by Invoice_date desc)=1)
) a
inner join 
(
select * from Adjust b 
qualify (row_number() over (partition by Shipment_Nbr order by Adjust_date desc)=1)
) b on (a.Shipment_Nbr=b.Shipment_Nbr)
inner join Charge c on (b.Uniq_Id=c.Uniq_Id)
)   -- FROM
```